# What forbids eating in a Jewish-owned restaurant open on shabbat?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, food, kashrut-kosher, restaurant

Many restaurants in Israel, when asked about their kashrut status, reply that they are open on Shabbat. Thus, no hechsher. This also exists in establishments that would have a relatively easy time obtaining an hechser, like an ice-cream shop.

My question is, if the ingredients are kosher, is there any real issue with buying from them on a weekday? Besides marit ayin and interests in boycotting non-religious establishments, what makes the food itself forbidden?

I don't think treif ingredients is very common in Israel, at least from my experience. It's hard for me to imagine secret treif and meat mixtures in an Israeli ice creamery, for example. What I'm more concerned about is whether a seller's trustworthiness to tell the truth (jeopardized by selling and cooking on Shabbat) is the only issue here, or is there something else that makes the food not kosher.

Does the lack of a mashgiach affect the status of food? Does a kli used for cooking on Shabbat affect the food made on a weekday? Would indirect attainment of such food b'dieved (receiving a scoop as a gift) be forbidden?

Sources would be gleefully appreciated.

Comment: Don't the dishes have to be kosher as well? Why do you limit yourself just to ingredients? An owner who does not care about Kashrus would think nothing of using a treif ingredient in a dish, or mixing meat and milk.

Comment: @ariel He mentions keilim in the question

Comment: @DoubleAA Only in the context of such a kli becoming treif because it was used on shabbos.

Comment: @Ariel Isn't that the relevant context here?

Comment: @Ariel - Don't forget that in Israel kosher ingredients are widely available. Anyone who wants to use treif ingredients will pay more and say "no we aren't kosher" (if that's not obvious from the menu) rather than "we are open on Shabbat" implying that the ingredients are kosher and that milk and meat are not mixed, at least not in cooking or in one serving. Aryeh is looking for a halachic basis for the **food** being forbidden.

Comment: @epicenter or they'll mix meat and milk and not tell anyone

Comment: @Epicentre Non kosher meat is available in Israel, and is cheaper than kosher. (You forget that there are plenty of non-Jews who live there too.)

Comment: @DoubleAA It's one of the contexts (and he could use an answer to that particular question). But the whole reason I made my initial comment is that I don't think the context is large enough. There is more involved than just the ingredients.

Comment: @Ariel Aren't stam keilim aino ben yomo? In any case, I don't think treif ingredients is as common in Israel, at east from my experience. It's hard for me to imagine secret treif and meat mixtures in an Israeli ice creamery, for example. What I'm more concerned about is whether a seller's trustworthiness to tell the truth (jeopardized by selling and cooking on Shabbat) is the only issue here, or is there something else that makes the food not kosher.

Comment: @Aryeh There are many potential kashrus problems even at an ice creamery, most of which would not be obvious to someone who is not knowledgeable about the field. There are many commonplace additives and flavorings that raise kashrus questions. Without supervision, the customer (and often the owner as well) has no way of knowing if the ice cream is reliable. This is probably doubly true in Israel, because of the many additional issues raised by mitzvos hatelyos ba'aretz, which can make even purely vegetable products problematic.

Comment: @LazerA But also easily fixable by being mafrish some ice cream as teruma etc. on the rest.

Comment: @DoubleAA You got the psak from a reliable source? Cause I can think of several potential problems with it.

Comment: FWIW, one of the Dunkin Donuts in Pittsburgh [is kosher](http://triblive.com/x/pittsburghtrib/lifestyles/fooddrink/s_647946.html) even though they're open on Saturday.  I couldn't find this online, but I remember reading in the Jewish press at the time that the Vaad ruled that since most of their customers are non-Jews being open on Shabbat didn't pose a problem for Jews eating there the rest of the week.  The article didn't spell out the reasoning and I never asked.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I asked about this to a local rav who is on the vaad and he said that while the vaad doesn't give a hechsher, historically, certain places that were Jewish owned and open (when there was no other alternative) were accepted. He said, though, that there would still be a qualitative difference between a bakery and a restaurant (and DD, owned by Jews, is more like a bakery because nothing is "made" there -- everything must be from a particular vendor and is simply assembled.)

Comment: @aryeh, Gleefully?

Comment: @SethJ I receive sources like a kosher ice-cream sundae!

Comment: FWIW circa 1980 there was a (IIRC) bakery in Albany, N.Y., which was open seven days a week under 'constant' (_t'midi_) supervision. Since the supervision wasn't there on _Shabas_, the products were certified kosher Tuesday through Friday or some such, and could not be bought at the start of the week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is forbidden to eat food that was produced by non-Jews or non-observant Jews (i.e. a Jew who is not fully observant of the laws of Shabbos) because it cannot be assumed to have been produced in accordance with the laws of kashrus. (This is true regardless of the producers assertions to the contrary. We cannot rely on the testimony of a non-Jew or non-observant Jew that the food is actually kosher.)

In such a case, the absence of a *hechsher* means that the food must be assumed to be non-kosher, even if "all the ingredients" are (supposedly) kosher.

This has nothing to do with *ma'aris ayin* (which only comes into affect when there is not actual halachic problem) or "boycotting non-religious establishments" (which I have never even heard of).

Moreover, nowadays we effectively require a *hechsher* even if the restaraunt is owned and run by a fully observant Jew. Even though, strictly speaking, in such a case supervision may not be required, in practical terms it is often necessary for several reasons. One reason is that, unless we know the owner ourselves (or live in their community), we have no way of knowing whether they are religious (or even Jewish), thus we would not be able to use their products. The hechsher, which is provided by a recognized entity in the Jewish world, solves this problem.

Secondly, the modern food industry is extraordinarily complex and any food production establishment that operates on a larger scale than a home kitchen requires knowledgeable supervision to ensure that no mistakes are made.

Thus, under normal circumstances, if a restaurant does not have a hechsher, the food must be assumed to be non-kosher, especially if the owners are not Shabbos observant Jews.

Comment: Not sure how this answers the question...

Comment: @double aa do you see the main question about the need for a hechsher or the status of keilim when there is no hechsher? The question as posted has many sub-questions.

Comment: @Dan I think it is pretty clear: what, aside from the lack of neemanus of the restaurateur due to his being mechallel shabbos, would forbid the food to be eaten on a weekday?

Comment: @DoubleAA The essense of the OP's question is, "My question is, if the ingredients are kosher, is there any real issue with buying from them on a weekday?" As my answer makes clear, yes, there is a real issue. (The various sub-questions read to me as attempts to suggest possible answers.)

Comment: @LazerA Then your answer doesn't apply because the given of the case was that the ingredients are kosher. (I assume here that when he assumes the ingrediants are all kosher he means that they are all dairy/pareve or all meat/pareve. That makes a lot of sense to be what he meant.) He is clearly trying to find out what **other** issues would apply.

Comment: @lazera I see the overarching question of whether a lack of hechsher because of one element is enough to affect unrelated elements at other times.  Your answer makes it clear that all elements are related.  The separate discussion above about keilim seems to present a possibility that things can be approached discretely.

Comment: @double aa lazera's answer questions the premise. All the ingredients are kosher only by the owner's say so which is not persuasive.

Comment: @Dan It doesn't matter why there is no hechsher. A hechsher is necessary to allow you to eat the food. The lack of a hechsher - for any reason - means that you have to assume the food is not kosher.

Comment: @Dan It doesn't matter. Something can be not-kosher for multiple reasons. Are there any issues besides his lack of neemanus? (eg maaseh shabbat, bishul akum, basar shenitalem min haayin or something else) That is the question.

Comment: @LazerA Can you source that? Certainly for thousands of years no one had hechshers.

Comment: @DoubleAA That premise is only significant if we are talking about the customer observing the owner open a sealed package of kosher ice cream (i.e. with a hechsher) and serving it to him using cold utensils. In such a case, there would, indeed, be no problem. Otherwise, the premise that "all the ingredients are kosher" is meaningless.

Comment: @DoubleAA Food from non-Jewish or non-observant Jews has always been forbidden. The only way to make it permitted was to have an observant Jew supervise the production. This is not new. What is new is the necessity for a religious Jew to have a hechsher, which I explained in the post.

Comment: @LazerA Stam keilim ainan ben yoman. What if he claims, eg no flavorings, and the government would fine him if he lied? You mean to tell me they always had hashgachas on pat paltar? What about stam milk in the supermarket in the USA?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6845/discussion-between-lazera-and-double-aa)

Comment: @LazerA You mention not hearing of the boycott issue. In Yalkut Yosef Shabbat 3 (102), it is ruled that one can buy from a bakery that's open on Shabbat if the food was baked on a weekday (even on a Sunday and one isn't sure if the bread is from Shabbat), as long as there is no doubt the bread is kosher. He prefaces the halacha by stating it is proper to refrain from buying there if an organized boycott will persuade the bakery to stop working on Shabbat.

Comment: The factories that produce and package food with widely accepted hechshers are open on Shabbat, people are working on Shabbat, food is shipped on Shabbat, etc. You accept this food as kosher to you because you see it on a shelf in the store with a hechsher. I tend to believe some of those restaurants could produce food with just as high kashrus 6 days a week as that food on the shelf.

Answer (score 2):

If the restaurant is open on Shabbos, is the Shabbos being publicly and knowingly violated there?

If it is, then the transgressors have the law of non-Jews. Their food will be [food cooked by a non-Jew "bishul akum"](http://halachafortoday.com/archives-2/archives-shabbos/) and forbidden.

Please see [Chazon Ish, Hilchos Shechita 2 (23)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14334&st=&pgnum=23).

Comment: Can you specify which date's entry in the link to look at?

Comment: Halachos for Wednesday, June 25 2008

1) Chazal say that one who keeps Shabbos is as if he has fulfilled the entire Torah. One who transgresses Shabbos is as if he has transgresed the entire Torah. **One who transgresses Shabbos in public [which means that 10 people are aware that this person is a mechalel Shabbos], is considered like a non Jew for all purposes; we may not drink his wine, his bread is considered bread of a non Jew etc.**

Comment: He does not mention bishul akum.

Comment: It's hidden in the word "etc." and implied by the fact that "his bread is considered bread of a non Jew".

Comment: Is his kiddushin not being a kiddushin hidden there too? What about his biah being posel a betulah from a kohen?

Comment: ונראה דפתו ושלקו דינו כיינו Please see Chazon Ish, Hilchos Shechita 2 (23) (http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14334&st=&pgnum=23)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6846/discussion-between-avrohom-yitzchok-and-double-aa)

Comment: Of course he quotes opinions the other way in the next line. Either way, if you have a source, why isn't it in your post?

Comment: I don't think this source is generally relied on nowadays.  Say a group of 9 is gathered Shabbat morning.  Another fellow drives up to join the minyan.  If we really believed that a modern public Shabbat violator was akin to a non-Jew, we still would have no minyan.

Comment: @Ze'evFelsen Can you provide a source please? I understand that we can be lenient about a tinok shenishba but what about a deliberate Shabbat violator?

Comment: Go and see what people do in terms of treating those who break Shabbat.  Some are willing to apply tinok sh'nishba to all or almost all modern sabbath violators.